# how to change the natural sort order in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have been using `<xsl:sort select="."/>` method to sort some values, Can i force the sort method to follow order as,

```
  i) sort numbers first
  ii) next greek symbols
  iii) and next english alphabets
```

What i get as output is,

```
 i) numbers
 ii) alphabets
 iii) greek symbols
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use three `xsl:sort` where the first tries to remove anything but digits e.g.

```
<xsl:sort select="xs:integer(replace(., '[^0-9]+', ''))"/>
```

then add a second sort

```
<xsl:sort select="replace(., '[^0-9a-z]+', '', 'i')"/>
```

to sort on the remaining Greek characters and lastly do

```
<xsl:sort select="replace(., '[^a-z]+', '', 'i')"/>
```

to sort on the English letters. If needed the regular expression would also allow you to define the range of Greek letters but I don't know there unicode numbers so if you need that you can look it up at unicode.org.